# A problem when using cmake to build a Fortran project with modules

Tags: cmake, fortran, gfortran

As a beginner of cmake, I'm trying to build a Fortran project with cmake. The source codes are encapsulated into different modules, which are located in different subfolders. However, it seems that the target library and executable file will not wait for the .mod file to be generated before compiling.

Below is part of my CMakeLists.txt file.

Thanks everyone!

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/utilities/)
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/utilities/)

file(GLOB srcFiles
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/utilities/*.f90
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/utilities/*.h
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/utilities/*.h
)
add_library(utilities STATIC ${srcFiles})
set_property(TARGET utilities PROPERTY LINKER_LANGUAGE Fortran)

file(GLOB srcFiles
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ui/*.f90
)
add_library(ui STATIC ${srcFiles})
target_link_libraries(utilities)
set_property(TARGET ui PROPERTY LINKER_LANGUAGE Fortran)

file(GLOB srcFiles
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/driver/*.f90)
add_library(driver STATIC ${srcFiles})
target_link_libraries(utilities ui)
set_property(TARGET driver PROPERTY LINKER_LANGUAGE Fortran)

add_executable(rse ${srcFiles})
target_link_libraries(utilities driver)
set_property(TARGET rse PROPERTY LINKER_LANGUAGE Fortran)

install(TARGETS rse RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
```

When I `use utilities` in driver module, it will report the error `Can't open module file ‘utilities.mod’ for reading at (1): No such file or directory.` And when I call a subroutine in driver module, it reports `` undefined reference to `__command_line_MOD_read_command_line' ``

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. Please show your error messages. Why exactly it seems?

Comment: When I ```use utilities``` in driver module, it will report the error ```Can't open module file ‘utilities.mod’ for reading at (1): No such file or directory```. And when I call a subroutine in driver module, it reports ```undefined reference to `__command_line_MOD_read_command_line'```

Comment: `target_link_libraries` expects the first argument to be the target. Your usage does not show that. So use `target_link_libraries(ui PUBLIC utilities)` for the first occurence and adapt the others as well.

Comment: It solves my problem. Very thanks!

Comment: `target_link_libraries` works fine when your build tree is purely hierarchical, but if you have circular dependencies (e.g. using submodules) then `add_dependencies` is a better way of defining the `use` hierarchy, in parallel to using `target_link_libraries` to define the linker dependencies.